# Data masking and when I need to use the Pick function

Tags: r, dplyr, concept, data-masking

I am currently working through R for data science and I am confused as to when you use the `pick` function to deal with data masking.

For example why does this work?

```
grouped_mean <- function(df, group_var, mean_var) {
 df |> 
   group_by({{ group_var }}) |> 
   summarize(mean({{ mean_var }}))
}

 diamonds %>% 
   grouped_mean(clarity, depth)
```

But this does not?

```
count_missing <- function(df, group_vars, x_var) {
  df |> 
    group_by({{ group_vars }}) |>  #this will not work because group by group_by use data masking
  summarize(
    n_miss = sum(is.na({{ x_var }})),
    .groups = "drop"
  )
}

flights |> 
  count_missing(c(year, month, day), dep_time)
```

But then this will.

```
count_missing <- function(df, group_vars, x_var) {
  df |> 
    group_by(pick({{ group_vars }})) |>  #here is the difference
    summarize(
      n_miss = sum(is.na({{ x_var }})),
      .groups = "drop"
    )
} 

flights |> 
  count_missing(c(year, month, day), dep_time)
```

I am just trying to understand the concept of when to use `pick()` vs `{{}}` or both.

Comment: The embracing operator, `{{` takes a single argument.  So `{{ c("var1", "var2") }}`, which is what you are trying to do, is illegal.  See [this](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/embrace-operator.html), [this](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/topic-data-mask.html) and [this](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/eval_tidy.html) for more detail.  `pick`, on the other hand, takes an ellipsis argument list, so can handle multiple, arbitrary, arguments.

Comment: This is incorrect. The issue here is that group_by is a data masking function, not a selecting function

Comment: @moodymudskipper my comment may or may not be relevant to OP's problem, but it is *factually* correct.  `{{` *does* take a single argument.  `pick` *does* take multiple, arbitrary arguments.

Comment: `{{` does take a single argument, but to feed it several args you would need to use `;`, here `c("var1", "var2")` is a single argument. `{{` does require a symbol though and it might have been what you meant, but it's irrelevant here because OP does feed it a symbol at all times.  It seems from your comment that the following would not work but it does: `cols <- c("mpg", "cyl") ; select(mtcars, {{ cols }})`

Answer (score 2):

No need for wrapper functions, this already fails:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(nycflights13)

flights |> 
  group_by(c(year, month, day)) |> 
  summarize(
    n_miss = sum(is.na(dep_time)),
    .groups = "drop"
  )
#> Error in `group_by()`:
#> ℹ In argument: `c(year, month, day)`.
#> Caused by error:
#> ! `c(year, month, day)` must be size 336776 or 1, not 1010328.
```

See in the doc `?group_by` how the `...` is documented, you don't see tidy-select as you do with `select()` and other selecting verbs (among them `across()` and `pick()`)

`group_by()` works more like mutate, you're not providing to it column names to be selected, but values that determine a group, so `c(year, month, day)` is not a tidy selection here but a vector 3 times longer than your df, hence the message.

At a lower level if you want to understand it, `pick()` will create a data frame from those columns, and `group_by()` will know how to handle it

```
flights |> 
  group_by(pick(c(year, month, day))) |> 
  summarize(
    n_miss = sum(is.na(dep_time)),
    .groups = "drop"
  )
#> # A tibble: 365 × 4
#>     year month   day n_miss
#>    <int> <int> <int>  <int>
#>  1  2013     1     1      4
#>  2  2013     1     2      8
#>  3  2013     1     3     10
#>  4  2013     1     4      6
#>  5  2013     1     5      3
#>  6  2013     1     6      1
#>  7  2013     1     7      3
#>  8  2013     1     8      4
#>  9  2013     1     9      5
#> 10  2013     1    10      3
#> # ℹ 355 more rows
```

The behavior of group_by() is confusing, but who needs group_by() anyway ? The `.by` arg uses tidy selection

```
flights |> 
  summarize(
    .by = c(year, month, day),
    n_miss = sum(is.na(dep_time)),
  )
#> # A tibble: 365 × 4
#>     year month   day n_miss
#>    <int> <int> <int>  <int>
#>  1  2013     1     1      4
#>  2  2013     1     2      8
#>  3  2013     1     3     10
#>  4  2013     1     4      6
#>  5  2013     1     5      3
#>  6  2013     1     6      1
#>  7  2013     1     7      3
#>  8  2013     1     8      4
#>  9  2013     1     9      5
#> 10  2013     1    10      3
#> # ℹ 355 more rows
```

Comment: @wurli if you can read this your answer is useful IMO, I don't think you should have deleted it